# Content Security Policy violation details missing on report-uri

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, content-security-policy, body-parser

Chrome is reporting Content Security Policy violations to the `report-uri`, but it reports no violation details. It reports `{}` instead of providing details regarding the violated policy.  All other browsers seem to be reporting violation details fine. My policy is provided below.

**I've tried...**

1. putting the full absolute path in the `report-uri` directive.
2. taking the policy out of `Report-Only` mode
3. making the policy much simpler e.g. `default-src 'none' ; report-uri /api/csp-report;`
4. turning off all my extensions (although I am seeing this in a production site from win & osx visitors with chrome)
5. testing in Canary
6. "Reported an issue" in chrome (I'm guessing it hasn't even been triaged yet)

**Questions I haven't found an answer for yet**

1. Is this implemented in Chrome yet?
2. Does the implementation differ from the spec?

**The Policy (Delivered via HTTP Header)**

> Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'none' ; script-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com; style-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self'
>   https://www.google-analytics.com ; font-src 'self'
>   https://fonts.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self'
>   https://api.servicesite.com; frame-src 'none' ; child-src 'none' ;
>   frame-ancestors 'none' ; form-action 'self' ;
>   upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; reflected-xss
>   block; base-uri https://*.mysite.com; referrer
>   origin-when-cross-origin; report-uri /api/csp-report;

### Update... Mar-16-2016

- Chrome is sending the report. I see the request body in network tab. Also logging it in intermediary nginx proxy.

That leads me to think this is a parsing issue in my receiving code (node, express using body-parser). However, still confounded as to why this would only happen for Chrome CSP reports. All other browser's reports pass though just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Chrome correctly sends CSP reports *"with a Content-Type header field of application/csp-report"* according to CSP spec level 2 (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#violation-reports)
- Other browsers are still sending `application/json` described in CSP spec level 1
- I'm accepting reports with nodejs + expressjs + body-parser. By default body-parser only parses requests with `content-type: application/json` Had to include `application/csp-report` as a valid content type to parse.

**Changed this...**

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

**To this...**

`app.use(bodyParser.json({type: ['application/json', 'application/csp-report']}));`